# Is there a site where I can get help figuring out what sort of A/V device I need?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wrote up a question at video.stackexchange.com, but based on the existing questions I was seeing, I got suspicious, then finally wised up and read the help only to find out that home theater systems are off-topic, so I didn't post it. Is there another place you can recommend that I ask this question?

---

## Q: Is such an A/V device available and could it work? Plus, better  search terms.

I'm having trouble finding the right kind of video device that I need. Maybe it's because I'm using the wrong search terms or I don't know the right sites to go to. Or maybe, it's because such a device doesn't/can't exist right now.

So, I'm not asking you for product recommendations, but to help me narrow on in the kind of devices (and the names needed to find them) that might do the job.

My use case is to be able to connect up many game systems, old and new, and have them all work correctly with a TV and a surround-sound audio system. I'm talking SNES all the way up to XBox One. And a record player. And ideally, connect my home automation system or Alexa or Google Home.

So here are my requirements as I imagine them:

- 4+ HDMI inputs. More is better. 8 would be ideal.
- 1+ RCA audio/video inputs. Full composite video is okay so long as it can detect when composite is not being used
- 1 HDMI out
- 1 SPDIF or appropriate optical audio out supporting Dolby 5.1 and possibly newer surround-sound specifications. (Is this correct or am I missing something here? What's the right output for a surround sound system?)
- 1 optical audio in (optional, though probably best)
- 1 RCA or mini-jack audio input, mini-jack preferred, separate from the combined audio/video RCA input above.
- 1 RCA or mini-jack audio output, mini-jack preferred
- Can independently select audio inputs and outputs separately from video. Examples:

  - HDMI input 1 is selected for both audio and video so both audio and video go to HDMI output.
  - HDMI input 1 is selected for video, but optical audio in is selected for audio. The device replaces the HDMI 1 audio with the optical audio, on top of the video stream.
- Will correctly pass-through HDMI device command (on & off) signals through for the currently selected input and output devices, such that if I have input 1 connected, selected, and I power it on, it sends the HDMI-on command through to the HDMI output.
- Ideally: If HDMI 2 input is selected, but not receiving a signal, and I turn on HDMI 1 which sends an HDMI-on command, it auto-switches. This feature can be turned off, or it is super good about detecting signals such that it won't mistakenly switch because of failing to detect a signal properly.
- Costs no more than $400
- All audio outputs can receive the same audio. There would never be a case of wanting to send HDMI input 1 audio to digital, and then send RCA input audio to HDMI output
- Can assign specific audio configurations to each video input such that when a video selection is made, say 1-4, it remembers which audio input to select (the audio from the mixed audio/video such as HDMI or RCA plugs, or one of the other audio inputs).
- Ideally: has an "audio-only" setting so that video can be turned off entirely (such as if I want to connect
- Ideally: has a remote control
- Bonus: can support ARC but this isn't a requirement, due to how the box can basically satisfy ARC on its own
- Bonus: accepts wireless networked audio input and output connections (Bluetooth?)
- Bonus: integrates with Alexa Home or Google Home or other popular home automation systems.
- Bonus: is controllable via network or interface so I can write my own software to do whatever I want.
- Bonus: could support selectable audio override/mixing so that if I, say, talk to Alexa or Google Home and they are responding, their audio can play over the same system, which mutes or radically lowers the volume of the existing audio stream, combining both audio sources. Also, a dedicated mode so the home automation system is the only audio present (if, say, reading a book through it).
- Mega-Bonus: Not sure how it would work, but, if a home automation system offers video calls, be able to do the same kind of override upon answering (so I could pause my game, and without switching inputs be able to take a video call right on my TV).

Notably, I don't need the video mixing abilities of the normal kind of device that might be able to support these requirements, and would cost thousands. There is no need for transitions, sending multiple screens to a single screen, splitting a single video input to multiple screens, and so on. There is no need for a video display on the device itself. Just independent video selector and audio selector buttons.

Some likely wrinkles I imagine are:

1. Such a device might not be possible for the price I suggested. That's okay, a higher price can be considered.
2. I suspect HDMI video may contain the audio embedded in each frame, so that cloning the video from an HDMI video stream actually involves decompressing the video. At that point, the delay in stripping and re-encoding the audio stream could make the audio and video out of sync. Plus, if it has to re-encode the video to replace its audio with that from a separate source, the video could be lower quality. Same issue with the audio. Being able to decompress and recompress would probably raise the price significantly.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been directed to [Hardware Recs.SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?